# send events from Azure Service Bus Topic to Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to send an event that is sent to Azure Service Bus topic to an event hub. Is this possible?

Details:
I am working with a different team in my company that receives third party events (via webhook) to Azure Service Bus topic and this is further used in different application.

My team wants to now listen/subscribe to this topic using our existing event hub and using azure capture store these events to a storage account.

I did the following:

I created a subscription to their topic in their Azure Service Bus.
I created an event hub in my Event hub namespace.

I am not sure, how to now connect the azure service bus topic subscription to send those events to my event hub.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @Suraj, Did my reply answer your question? If yes, kindly mark it as the answer so the community is aware that this question has been closed. If not, kindly let us know what other doubts you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service bus operates with the receivers having to pull messages from it. This is opposite to Eventgrid which pushes the events to its subscribers. Eventhub does not pull messages from the source, we need to push messages into it. So you cannot achieve your requirement without an extra component between Service Bus and Eventhub.

One of the possible components would be a service bus topic triggered azure function [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp) which writes into the eventhub using output binding [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=csharp) or the SDK [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send).

You will need to choose your service plan carefully depending on the volume of messages expected but usually Consumption plan will suit this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Anupam for the details! I will use Azure function.